# Realm JavaScript Object Notification

Tags: javascript, realm

In the Swift version of Realm, you can get notifications on a given object. For instance

```
class Test: Object { ... }
let t = Test()
t.observe { ... }
```

However, this functionality does not seem to exist in the realm-js documentation. My question is if anybody has been able to implement notifications for a particular object in Realm JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, Realm JS doesn't currently support object notifications. The issue is https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/763.